# Unit -.mount mount does not exist, proceeding anyway

Tags: mount, xubuntu, encryption, gparted

I installed fresh Xubuntu using [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption) because I needed my disc encrypted. After installation, when I tried to run `gparted`, I had errors which I partly fixed by reinstalling some libraries. Now when I type `sudo gparted`, the following shows up in terminal:

```
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
======================
libparted : 3.2
======================
```

`gparted` starts after this. I never had this problem before this install, I used exact same system. Even though `gparted` works, I'm not happy having this error in terminal. Does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Searching online for that error, it appears to be experienced by many, and is a known bug. I also had had the same issue with the libraries, and I followed the very same ManualFullSystemEncryption guide a few days ago.

More on all of this here [18.04: 'Command 'gparted' not found... gparted is already the newest version'](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2409234)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it reads: *Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.*, but GParted works flawlessly though, so I’d say: no worries!